# Find $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^6+y^6}{x^3+y^3}$ using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, epsilon-delta

My textbook asks the question

> $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^6+y^6}{x^3+y^3}$$
> Does $f(x,y)$ have a limit as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$?

I used polar coordinates instead of solving explicitly in $\mathbb R^2 $, and it went as the following:

$$ x = r \cos \theta, \qquad y = r\sin\theta $$

Hence,

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^6+y^6}{x^3+y^3} = \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{{r^6\cos^6\theta + r^6\sin^6\theta}}{r^3\cos^3\theta + r^3\sin^3\theta}$$

This simplifies to,

$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^3({\cos^6\theta + \sin^6\theta})}{\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta}$$

Now from the above, we find that as r→$0$ the limit is $0$.

So now i have got $0$ as a possible limit.I have tried to procceed further using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition but I cannot get anywhere.

Any thoughts on how to prove that $0$ is in fact the limit?

Comment: You need to make sure that you're accounting for the cases when the denominator approaches zero, i.e. when $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}$, in which case the limit may be different.

Comment: So you say that the limit is not 0 after i used the polar coordinates?

Comment: You can't quite conclude that the limit exists from your work so far. You need to check if $\frac{\cos^6 \theta + \sin^6 \theta}{\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta}$ is a bounded function of $\theta$. If it is, then the absolute value of your function is less than $Mr^3 = M \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}^3$ for some $M$, and the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof is easy from there. If it's unbounded, then your limit will not exist (you can find points arbitrarily close to $0$ which have large values, based on the function of $\theta$ blowing up). You need to figure out if the $\theta$ function is bounded!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to prove that it is infact a bounded function of $\theta$? I have actually tried proving it using the original function with x and not the polar coordinates but i have had no luck there.

Comment: Well, given that this $\theta$ function is periodic (as always) and a quotient of two continuous functions, the only possible way that this function is unbounded is if there is a point of discontinuity, and the only place a point of discontinuity can exist is where the denominator tends to $0$. The denominator is still continuous, so this must be where $\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta = 0$. First, are there such points? Solve the equation to decide. If there are, does the numerator also tend to $0$ at those values? If not, your function is unbounded.

Comment: The solutions of $\theta$ are $(3*\pi)/4$ and $(7*\pi)/4$ but in the numerator these solutions do not tend to $0$. So i can conclude that function of $\theta$ is unbounded. Does this actuallly mean that the limit of my original function does not exist? Because in Wolfram Alpha the solution it gives is that $0$ is in fact the limit.

Comment: @ΜάριοςΤσοκανάς It doesn't exist. Let's say you pick $r = \delta$. Then you can choose some $\theta$ such that$$\left|\frac{\cos^6 \theta + \sin^6 \theta}{\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta}\right| > \frac{1}{\delta^3}.$$The point $(r, \theta)$, in polar coordinates, will evaluate to a number of modulus greater than $1$, while being $\delta$-close to $0$, for any arbitrary $\delta > 0$. This is sufficient to show the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for yout time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top tip: don't trust wolfram! It gets the answer wrong sometimes!

Suppose we set $y = x$ and take $x \to 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y(x)) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^6+y^6}{x^3+y^3} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^6}{2x^3}\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
Now let's suppose we take $y = -x$ and take $x \to 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y(x)) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^6+y^6}{x^3+y^3} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^6}{x^3 - x^3}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^6}{0}
\end{align*}
which is undefined. Since we have two approaches of $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ that give different results, the overall limit must not exist.